# Send Json over websocket

Tags: javascript, python, json, websocket

I have a JavaScript client and Python tornado server. I am sending messages in Json format strings back and forth. here is my JavaScript function:

```
var message = {};
var senders
message["messageKey"] = "title";
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$.getJSON("sample.json", function(json) {
    message["data"]= json;
    senders =  jsonToStrConvert(message);
    });

function jsonToStrConvert(mes)
{
 var getBack= JSON.stringify(mes);
 return getBack;
}
```

It basically takes the data from a json file, convert it to string object and send it through.

On the server side, python with tornado framework:

```
    JsonMessage = json.loads(message)
    self.write_message(JsonMessage['messageKey'])
```

It works fine, even with relatively large Json payload. After convert the string message to dictionary, I can freely do anything with it. However, sometimes for unknown reasons, I got error like this:

```
connection opened
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception in /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 494, in _run_callback
    result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "index.py", line 29, in on_message
    JsonFormattedMessage = json.loads(message)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
connection closed
```

The error happens under the same circumstances when it works, both server and client on the same network. happens with the same json payload that worked before. 
I have absolutely no knowledge about networking. Is there any better web-sockets server to use? may be specific for JSON? Is there any cashe or something I can refresh to prevent that error? I searched alot and could not find a better reliable way?

Comment: i used to get this error message, when the request is of incorrect format.

Comment: All I get a after waiting few seconds and try again with absolutely no changes is working software @KalyanReddy